# jQuery JSON feed not getting pulled in

Tags: jquery, json

We have a json feed from a database that lists college campuses by state. I can't seem to get the content to get pulled into the page.

I have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/richcoy/uQftN/) setup.

Simple HTML code:

```
<h2>Campuses</h2>
<div id="state"></div>
```

The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("http://ml.uscm.org/ministries.json?state=CA&active=true",
        function (data) {
        $.each(data, function () {
            $.each(this, function (key, value) {
                $("#state").append(
                    "Name: " + value.name + "<br />" +
                    "City: " + value.city + "<br />" +
                    "State: " + value.state + "<br />");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

A direct link to the example json:

http://ml.uscm.org/ministries.json?state=CA&active=true

Comment: Hmmm,  XMLHttpRequest cannot load json from a different domain .. you need to use `jsonp`

Comment: Are you getting json data, please check your browser console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this (using jsonp, notice the callback parameter in the url)

```
$.getJSON("http://ml.uscm.org/ministries.json?state=CA&active=true&callback=?", function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
        $("#state").append(
            "Name: " + value.name + "<br />" +
            "City: " + value.city + "<br />" +
            "State: " + value.state + "<br />");
    });
});
```

[**Working Fiddle Here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/uQftN/1/)
Read more on [**jQuery site**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) about `jsonP`.